# Не могу Datagrid связать с ObservableCollection<>

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть Datagrid по имени list
`<DataGrid Width="300" Height="300" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" x:Name="list">   </DataGrid>`

В коде wpf я создал ObservableCollection<>

```
ObservableCollection<Ourdata> carlist = new ObservableCollection<Ourdata>();
```

Класс Ourdata выглядит следующим образом.

```
    public class Ourdata
{
    public string A {get;set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
}
```

При выполнении `list.ItemsSource = carlist;` выбивается ошибка.

> "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation"

Коллекция carlist не пустая объекты добавляются и сохраняется там без проблем.В чём может быть ошибка?
В Inner exception следующая ошибка "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: А что в `InnerException`? Сделайте `exception.ToString()` и добавьте это в вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

В конструкторе `MainWindow` я не прописал `InitializeComponent();`.

Comment: Это ответ или дополнение?

Comment: Это ответ на мой вопрос.

Comment: хорошо, понял )